# Z-index issue on navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some issues with my navbar menu for my site. I want to have the main menu, a sub menu and a sub menu to that. So 3 levels total.

So far I have gotten the 2 levels to work, but I cannot get the 3rd level to go under the 2nd with z-indexing. Currently they are only on the same index it appears.

Anything I've tried messes up with the jQuery script I did for displaying the `select` instead of the menu when on small screens.

So how can I do this?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/upjagu9w/1/) (Go Products > Oticon).

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <select class="menu_mobile_top">
        <option>Home</option>
        <option>Services</option>
        <option>Products</option>
        <option>Shop</option>
        <option>Prices</option>
        <option>About</option>
        <option>Contact</option>
    </select>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">                    
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Services</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Service 1</a>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Service 2</a>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Service 3</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Products</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Phonak</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">ReSound</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Siemens</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Starkey</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Widex</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Oticon</a>
                        <ul class="subnavoptions">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Unitron</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Bernafon</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #304770;
    z-index: 10;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 34pt;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #99C2EC;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #99C2EC;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #99C2EC;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #99C2EC;
}

.bodyframe {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.div_container {
    max-width: 1460px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo-div {
    padding: 15px 0 10px;
}

.logo-div div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #304770;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-offset {
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    background: #304770;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #304770;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: static;
}

.nav li a {
    padding: 12px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    display: block;
}

.nav li.active a {
    color: orange;
}

.nav > li.active > a:before {
    width: 100%;
}

.nav li:hover > a {
    background-color: #304770;
    color: orange;
    transition: color 0.25s;
}

.nav > li > a:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: orange;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.2s;
    -o-transition: width 0.2s;
    transition: width 0.2s;
}

.nav > li:nth-last-of-type(1) > a:after {
    display: none;
}

.nav li a:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}

.nav > li > a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    top: 21px;
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #ffffff;
    opacity: .5;
}

.nav li:hover .subnav {
    top: 49px;  
}

.subnav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #304770;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    transition: top 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.2s;
    -o-transition: top 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.subnav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.subnav li a {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #304770;
    display: block;
}

.subnav li:hover .subnavoptions {
    top: 36px;  
}

.subnavoptions {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #304770;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -2;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    transition: top 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.2s;
    -o-transition: top 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.subnavoptions li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.subnavoptions li a {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #304770;
    display: block;
}

.menu_mobile_top {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    top: 5px;
    background-color: #2A333F;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 3px;
}

.menu_mobile_top:focus, option:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can give a higher z-index to a child element of a parent with a lower z-index.  If you have a nav at `z-index:1`, then subNav at `z-index:2`, it doesn't really matter.  the `z-index:2` is only relative to it's siblings.  Unless you make everything `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the styles defined for third level menu. Add the following and try.

```
.subnavoptions li a li{
top:50px;
```

}

Comment: `.subnavoptions li` are the 3rd level items.